# Microsoft bot framework with Instgram

Tags: botframework

I was trying to build a bot using Microsoft bot framework and connect it with Instagram but I only found a graph APIs for instagram. can anyone please help & advise?

Comment: For future reference, please review this helpful [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a question to the Stack Overflow community.

Answer (score 0):

The BotFramework service only supports specific channels. Anything outside of those channels requires a custom adapter to be constructed to facilitate communication between the bot and the unsupported service. This is typically done by building a custom adapter. There are examples in the botbuilder-community repos that you can use to help design yours. Both the [dotnet](https://github.com/BotBuilderCommunity/botbuilder-community-dotnet/tree/develop/libraries) and [JS](https://github.com/BotBuilderCommunity/botbuilder-community-js/tree/master/libraries) libraries contains several adapters that you can reference.